# How to access the ProgramFiles environment variable from nmake on x64 machines?

Tags: environment-variables, nmake

I try to get the path to the `ProgramFiles` environmental variable, that is supposed to expand to `C:\Program Files (x86)` on a `x64` machine and to `C:\Program Files` on a `x86` machine.

The problems is that in the nmake file if I do:

```
 all:
      echo $(PROGRAMFILES)
```

This will expand to `C:\Program Files` everytime and this is wrong.

Environment details from a x64 machine:

```
ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)
ProgramW6432=C:\Program Files

:: this one is special, if will return different results based on current process x86/x64
ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files (x86) or C:\Program Files
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=x86 or x64
```

Now the updated question is **how to get the location of x86 program files inside nmake, in a way this will work on both x86 and x64 machines**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This expression seems to work on 64-bit Windows 7, with `nmake` running in both 32-bit and 64-bit:

```
%%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%%
```

e.g.

```
LC = %%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\lc.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're on an x64 machine it is totally legal that `%ProgramFiles%` points to `C:\Program Files` - from within a 64-bit program's environment.
The variable you have to use to get the x86 counterpart is `%ProgramFiles(x86)%`.

Which one to use can be determined by evaluating the current OS's architecture that is set in the `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE` environment variable (which is e.g. set to `AMD64`). Or simply try to get `%ProgramFiles(x86)%` and if it is empty get the content of `%ProgramFiles%`.

Another approach would be to start a 32-bit `cmd.exe` and run your make there. It is located in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`.

Comment: I updated the question to explain better the reasoning (mainly I need this value in order to properly locate include directories). Also if you know a way to read values from the registry, but I'm pretty sure nmake does not supports this.